# Jquery Tree chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, graph

I am looking for javascript or jquery solution that can perform following tasks:

```
1 - Dynamically generate tree (hierarchy structure of data)
2 - Add/delete single and multiple nodes.
3 - Zoom option for graph area
4 - labels for each node
```

I want to use it for data analysis

Comment: i'm not clear on the 'Zoom' option for graph area item...

Comment: but what about other options?

Comment: Voting to close as tool rec.

Answer (score 10):

You could use [arbor.js](http://arborjs.org) or build yourself a wrapper around the [arrows-and-boxes](http://www.headjump.de/article/arrows-and-boxes) plugin.

Answer (score 4):

if you want a great library , try the Data-Driven Documents library.

[d3js library.](http://d3js.org/)

Here is an [example](http://bl.ocks.org/4063570)

Comment: very very nice examples

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean a tree like a jstree?
See http://www.jstree.com/

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite old, but for anyone who hasn't seen these libraries:
[vis.js](http://visjs.org/) and [Treant.js](http://fperucic.github.io/treant-js/) are quite good visualization libraries.

Comment: I down voted this because both options don't meet the 2 first tasks requested (1 - Dynamically generate tree / 2 - Add/delete single and multiple nodes)

Answer (score 0):

[Jit](http://philogb.github.io/jit/demos.html) - JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit on Github.com is beautiful.