# javascript library for building tree-node hierarchy

Tags: javascript, tree, family-tree

I am looking for JavaScript library that can perform the following tasks:

1. Dynamically generate tree (graph-node) (hierarchy structure of data)
2. Can connect nodes together
3. Zoom option for graph area
4. labels for each node

Basically, like [familyecho.com](http://familyecho.com)? Where can I find a library that has the same functionality? If any of you know any library that can perform all these task, then please do reply me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery Tree chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290116/jquery-tree-chart)

Comment: Voting to close as tool rec.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try infovis: https://philogb.github.io/jit/

Tree example: https://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example1.html

Comment: can I connect two nodes in the same row?

Comment: I don't know. You need to explore the API docs and see the examples. Trees don't have nodes of the same level connected. The only connection allowed in trees is parent to child. The example that you showed connect the children, but it is just to show that they are siblings.

Comment: just what I was looking for!