# Javascript Hierarchy/Tree creator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Does anyone know of a javascript or css hierarchy plugin that will accomplish the following:

```
Root
|  |
|  |
M1  M2
|  |
\  /
  E
```

One that will basically do this, start with a root, branch off to two or more nodes, and the possibility that the nodes can meet on a child element below.

Thanks

Comment: Voting to close as tool rec. Similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4290116/jquery-tree-chart

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You may just need to reverse this.. 
[CSS3 Family Tree](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree)

Otherwise you can use Canvas for drawing your required tree structure

Or you can use [jsPlumb Library](https://github.com/sporritt/jsPlumb). See some [samples here](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/demos.html)

Also checkout [JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit](http://philogb.github.com/jit/demos.html) and [GoJS](http://gojs.net/) libraries.

Also checkout [D3 library](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Hierarchy-Layout). [Demo1](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083), [Demo2](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339184), [Demo3](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2966094)

Comment: not quite what i'm after, I already tried another solution based off of <ul> and <li> and it doesn't quite work the way we want. May need some javascript to do what we want, thanks though!

Comment: I went through every one of these, thanks for the post. I need the JS libraries as well. Most things are for directory structures.

Comment: I can't get over how extensive and well done d3js is.  Their main demo page is absolutely stunning.  [https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery)

Answer (score 3):

Ended up using the original idea we had and went with http://astuteo.com/slickmap/ which makes some nice looking hierarchy trees.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this advanced diagram builder.
this [demo](https://js.syncfusion.com/demos/jquery/dashboard/diagrambuilder/default.html) is for syncfusion. that create all type of workflow & has advanced toolbar like windows application.